# On the fly modification of Django QuerySet objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to add two attributes to every object in the queryset and add one more to a specific subset:

```
causelist_data = CauseHierarchy.objects.filter(cause_set_version_id=cause_set_version_id
    ).extra(order_by=['sort_order']
    ).prefetch_related('cause_id','parent_id')

for c in causelist_data:
    # adding this attribute works
    c.display_name = c.cause_id.cause_name + " (" + c.cause_id.acause + ")"
    if len(c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')) == 1:
        # adding this attribute works as well
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-1]
    else:
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-2]

    # this is the problem
    parent = causelist_data.filter(cause_id=c.immediate_parent)[0]
    parent.is_parent = True
```

The modification works when I add a display name to each object and when I add an immediate_parent attribute based on a conditional. The problem arises when I try to set an is_parent attribute to objects that have been identified as children by pulling their id as each object identifies its parent in the iteration.

In the shell I tried to print the `parent` object within the loop and it has the is_parent attribute, but when I look at causelist_data outside of the loop it has both the display_name and the immediate_parent attributes. I also tried to update the parent object after the filter (`parent = causelist_data.filter(cause_id=c.immediate_parent).update(is_parent=True)`), but it looks like I can't add an attribute like that, only update.

Am I missing something here? Is my lookup incorrect?

Comment: Modifying the `parent` object I created does not modify the original QuerySet. I figured out a way to do it by iterating over the QuerySet 3 times, but it's not pretty. If you have suggestions I'd love to see them on the [code review question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101426/changing-attributes-in-django-objects-outside-of-iteration) that I just posted.

Comment: A queryset cannot be modified after you take a slice of it or start iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

I think in all cases you would issue another query 
Get a better hold on your `filters` and you should be fine.

```
filters = {cause_set_version_id:cause_set_version_id}

causelist_data = CauseHierarchy.objects.filter(filters**
).extra(order_by=['sort_order']
).prefetch_related('cause_id','parent_id')

for c in causelist_data:
    # adding this attribute works
    c.display_name = c.cause_id.cause_name + " (" + c.cause_id.acause + ")"
    if len(c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')) == 1:
        # adding this attribute works as well
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-1]
    else:
        c.immediate_parent = c.path_to_top_parent.split(',')[-2]

    filters['cause_id'] = c.immediate_parent
    parent = CauseHierarchy.objects.filter(filters**)[0]

    parent.is_parent = True
```